# How to dump/restore only diff data between the old and the new database

Tags: postgresql, diff, restore, dump, continuous-delivery

We have a big postgresql database and actually we deliver the whole dump file... so it take too much time to be dumped and later restored !
Is there a lightest way to be able to dump only diff data in a specific schema and restore only that diff data (creating the new table, updating the same modified tables, and deleting the deleted ones) ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: diff to between what and what?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev between two different databases having the same schema (old and new)